# jquery change something added by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i have a problem with onchange event in jquery. 
the event added dont work

This is my code:

```js
<script>
    
    jQuery("#select1").on('change',
            function(event)
            {       
              event.preventDefault();  
               jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    url: '<?php echo Router::Url(array('controller' => 'XXX','admin' => TRUE, 'action' => 'onChangeSelect1Ajax'), TRUE); ?>',
                    success: function(response) {
                        
                        jQuery('#select2Position').empty().append(response);
                      
                    },
                  error: function(response) { 
                      
                    alert('error');  
                    },
                    data:{ idselect1 : this.value }
                });
                return false;
 
            }
    );


    jQuery("#select2").on('change',
            function(event)
            {       
              event.preventDefault();    
               jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    url: '<?php echo Router::Url(array('controller' => 'XXX','admin' => TRUE, 'action' => 'onChangeSelect12Ajax'), TRUE); ?>',
                    success: function(response) {
                        
                        jQuery('#other').empty().append(response);
                      
                    },
                  error: function(response) { 
                      
                    alert('error');  
                    },
                    data:{ idselect1 : jQuery("#select1").value, idselect2 : this.value }
                });
                return false;
 
            }
    );


</script>
```

When i'm change select1, select2 is added. 
but select2 onchange event dont working.
could you help me please?

thanks

Comment: can you explain more on `but select2 onchange event dont working` also include HTML mark in snippet

Comment: wrap your code in `$(function() {` *your code here* `});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding `select2` dynamically then you need to use `event` delegation technique to attach `event` to it as follows:

```
jQuery(document).on('change',"#select2",
            function(event)
            {       
              event.preventDefault();    
               jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    url: '<?php echo Router::Url(array('controller' => 'XXX','admin' => TRUE, 'action' => 'onChangeSelect12Ajax'), TRUE); ?>',
                    success: function(response) {

                        jQuery('#other').empty().append(response);

                    },
                  error: function(response) { 

                    alert('error');  
                    },
                    data:{ idselect1 : jQuery("#select1").value, idselect2 : this.value }
                });
                return false;

            }
    );
```

I am sure it will solve your issue.